# How do you get JSTL fmt tag to formate negative numbers with ()

Tags: java, jstl, fmtonly

How can I get the JSTL fmt tag to format negative numbers with ()?  For example, if I have -20, it would show (20).  Positive numbers would be normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to use pattern to do this, but if you use type="currency" you get the parens

```
<fmt:formatNumber type="currency" value="${line.volume}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown what patterns you tried, but I would expect something like:

"#;(#)"

would work...